# how to do error handling in jmeter for log out in case of error

Tags: jmeter-5.0

i want to add a step in a jmeter script so as to log out in case of any sample error , and continue next thread , can someone please help me out , how to set an error handling step as to jump to the log out step if any sample error is found .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSR223 to write a script, you can put the status of step into a variable then using the function if in Jmeter.